# adding new property based on spring profile

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

If spring boot is run in `override` profile , can we have application-override.properties having properties like `foo.baz` that is not defined in application.properties ?

application.properties

```
foo.bar=1
```

application-override.properties

```
spring.profiles.include=default 
foo.baz=1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create configuration class for your custom profile and load the appropriate properties file in it like this:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("override")
@PropertySource("classpath:application-override.properties")
public class OverrideConfig {

}
```

This way, all the configuration you do in OverrideConfig (including taking properties from application-override.properties), will only load if override profile is enabled in application.properties like this:

```
spring.profiles.active=override
```

Comment: I am not convinced about using `@PropertySource` according to the question. It may helpful if you want to define some specific conf/beans according for this profile. That is not the case in the question. Note also that `@PropertySource("classpath:application-override.properties")` is probably not required since the activated profile should already look for `application-override.properties` in the expected locations.

Answer (score 3):

That is correct. When you have new properties in `application-override.properties` and and the override profile is the active profile, then yes in your program the properties from `application.properties` as wel as `application-override.properties` is loaded.

Using `spring.profiles.include=default` in your override profile is not needed.

**In the case of loading multiple specific profiles with same properties:**

Also, in the context of property overriding with profiles, something to keep in mind when you have multiple active profiles and they contain the same property. The last profile in the list will be used.

Let's say you start up your program with `mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.profiles=profile1,profile2`

Both `application-profile1.properties` and `application-profile2.properties`
contains the property `my.custom-property=x` (for profile1) and `my.custom-property=y` (for profile2). The value of `my.custom-property` will be `y`, as that was the last profile in the provided profiles.

Answer (score 2):

Long story short : Spring boot overrides values of properties with same name according to [their evaluation order](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html).  But here **you don't override** any property, **you add** a new.

That is still simpler : Spring boot just adds it into the Spring Environment.
Just run the app by specifying this profile and makes sure that the properties are located in the locations expected by Spring Boot.

Example from a fat jar (Java system property) :

```
java -Dspring.profiles.active=override -jar foo.jar
```

Example from the source code (Maven property) :

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=override
```

Comment: The above problem will be solved by just using `@profile` annotation right? he don't need to use `@PropertySource` unless override.properties is in different location, is that right?

Comment: @Deadpool Annotating `@Profile("override")` makes the bean class to be loaded when the profile is activated at the startup of the container. But why loading a specific bean for activating a profile ? It is not the OP requirement... He needs neither  `@PropertySource` nor `@Profile`, only to run the app by specifying the profile (`java -Dspring.profiles.active=override -jar foo.jar`) About your last remark you are right, it may be for the location but also the file name itself if it is not the expected default.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this by simply add the profile name to the `application.properties`:

```
application-override.properties
```

Then you can load profile from the command line:

```
java -jar foo.jar --spring.profiles=override
```

source: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html#howto-change-configuration-depending-on-the-environment

Spring will load the `application.properties` first followed by any `application-{profile}.properties`.

---

Another option is to use yaml, and load everything into one file:

```
foo:
  bar: 1

---

spring:
  profiles: override
foo:
  baz: 1

---

spring:
  profiles: otherOverride
foo:
  bar: 2
  baz: 2
```